# Forms in Webkit HTML Notifications?

Tags: forms, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, notifications

Is it possible to use form elements in Webkit HTML desktop notifications? I'm tried to open a HTML notification from a Chrome extension, and the `<input>` I added appears, but I cannot type in it. I'd like to be able to capture the input from it and save it.

```
var notification = webkitNotifications.createHTMLNotification(chrome.extension.getURL('input-prompt.html'));
notification.show();

<html>
<body>
<form><input type="text" name="here" value="test" /></form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's called a notification for a reason. It's meant to have the bare minimum or interactivity if any at all, and breaking that rule will likely annoy your users.

Comment: Star this bug to vote for it and receive email updates on it. http://crbug.com/56764

Answer (score 3):

You can get around this in a pretty simple way. You can create a div that serves as your input box, and allow the content of the div to be edited ([look here](http://googlecode.blogspot.com/2011/04/new-test-suite-for-rich-text-editing.html)). Then you can use a button or another div as the submit button, then handle the form submit with javascript.

```
<div contenteditable="true" id="inputBox"></div>
<div id="submitButton" onclick="submitform();">Submit</div>
```

While I agree that desktop notifications are probably not meant to contain forms, I have a case where having a form in the notification is actually more convenient. I hope this helps.

Comment: Same issue, box shows that it has focus, but cannot type in it

Comment: in new notification api, html is not even allowed.

Answer (score 2):

Notifications are not meant for interactivity. They are meant to notify.

If you want to have interactivity, use an **[Action](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/browserAction.html)** instead.

Comment: Agreed. If you want to notify about a form - link to it.